# Rails reject fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

I'm trying to achieve the same thing for nested attributes but for first level attributes.
I would like to reject/ignore/skip some fields if a Proc evaluates to true.
Is there anyway of doing this without define a before_save hook?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mean [validations?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validation-helpers

If you want to set some fields to `nil` before saving it, the best way is to do that with a `before_save` or `before_create`.

Comment: No... I actually mean (silently) ignore an object's field while saving.
I have an object and one or more of its fields need to be ignored (not persisted) if let's say the "status" field is "false".

Comment: Nothing really wrong I was just wondering if there's a cleaner method that I was missing due to my poor experience

Comment: Nope. If you want to set some fields to `nil` before saving it, the best way is to do that with a `before_save` or `before_create`.